# Forcing two or more custom post type to be private

Tags: custom-post-types, private

I registered a new custom post type and forced it to be private, but now I need to use three custom post type. I registered the second one, but I don't know hot to set the code to force the second one.

Here is the code I used to force the first CPT ('my_post_type1')

```
function force_type_private($post)
{
    if ($post['post_type'] == 'my_post_type1') {
        $post['post_status'] = 'private';
    }
    return $post;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'force_type_private');
```

How can I force the second ('my_post_type2')?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

> You can add multiple compared condition variable in single if condition using logical OR operator.

For more knowledge of Logical condition [click](https://www.w3resource.com/php/operators/logical-operators.php)

```
function force_type_private($post)
    {
        if ($post['post_type'] == 'my_post_type1' || $post['post_type'] == 'my_post_type2') {
            $post['post_status'] = 'private';
        }
        return $post;
    }
    add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'force_type_private ');
```

Comment: Thank you very much @HK89. Now my second post-type is private, but there is a difference between the first and the second: in the Dashboard I see the label "private" near the title of the post of type 1, but there is no label near the post of type 2. 
Can you explain me the reason?
Thanks

Comment: Add your screeshot of  both bost type i am check .

Comment: I added a screenshot.
I also have one more problem in Production environment, because it seems I (Admin) have no permission to create content of the second CPT. How is ithis possible?
Thank you very much for your attention and your time

Comment: More precisely: I have no permission to create any content of CPT, but I have already created a one a few time ago. I don't understand what happened